# Could adding a "read this" improve the new user experience?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm hardly a heavy user, but I've posted to SO over the years and understand the basics -- ask specific questions that have specific answers, show your work, don't ask for homework help, etc. By now, I don't need to be told that when I visit SO.

But I just went to Code Review, and being a total noob there, I figured I should find out if what I want to post is ok to post there. I *think* it is, based on the name (Code Review), but I don't see anything upon arriving at the page that tells me what is and what isn't on topic. Here's what I see:

[image]

Forum software generally has a "sticky" feature that makes designated posts always appear at the top, and forum administrators use this feature to tell visitors what the place is about and what the expectations are.

Comment: [There's information available about what is and isn't okay in the tour...](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)  and in your defense, it's not well exposed.  But all sites have the same tour link and it all lives in the same location, as well as offering a badge for taking it.

Comment: @Makoto Indeed, you are correct. And I took the tour, but I guess it looked so much like marketweb blah-blah-blah that my eyes glazed over. I realize that many forums have a read-the-riot-act approach to their FAQ, but maybe that prevents a lot of "bad" questions, not to mention the hurt feeling of the askers when the community shames them for asking "bad" questions.

Comment: You might have hit the nail on the head of the actual problem:  "my eyes glazed over".  This isn't a dig at you necessarily but this is what happens when users are exposed to a giant wall of text stating, "Read this or be forever chastised."  If I'm going to be blunt I don't think anything would fix that.  Not anything that we have or know today, anyway.

Comment: (I don't agree with "don't ask for homework help". Homework questions are welcome, as long as an attempt has been made, and the asker is not being obviously lazy by asking people to do their work for them.)

Comment: It's clear that the designers who worked on the call-to-action prefer streamlining the signup experience for new users to having them read required documentation they'd probably rather not read.

Comment: @BoltClock the downside to that is new users wasting time and effort writing questions, skilled and experienced SO user-moderators wasting time and effort downvoting an closing them, new users and others wasting time and effort posting 'unhelpful, hostille bullying mobs' meta posts and other meta users wasting time and effort refuting those insulting allegations.  If nothing save personal moral integrity and honour prevents new users from posting 'teach me basic syntax for free' questions, they wil post them, and the cycle continues,. wasting time and effort.  Every Sunday, close the same:(

Comment: Once you've seen a few different sites' tours, you will realise where exactly to look for the only new piece of information: what is on- and off-topic on that particular site. The rest of the tour text is, AFAICT, identical on all sites. Perhaps the system could be enhanced by having two tours, one for "I've never seen an SE site before" and one for "I know my way around the SE format, just give me this site's specific."

Comment: The "read this or else" approach won't work because, 1) many people ignore it, 2) other people read it and fail to understand it, 3) other people read it notionally understand it but think that i doesn't apply to them ... 'cos some invalid reason.  The only thing I think would work is to force people to take a (separate) quiz before allowing them to post Questions, Answers, review ... and other things where we want people to conform to the "norms" of the community.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Ways to give users some specific education about question quality and topicality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277607/165773)

Comment: People already disregard the suggested similar questions when typing up their question.  Do you think a “read this” is going to solve anything when most people wouldn’t even be asking a question if they just RTFM?

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, it isn't necessary.

This is primarily because a 'new user experience' rarely involves going to the homepage. Certainly in my case, I discovered Stack Overflow through googling for answers. It quickly becomes clear what the site is about and type of community that it is, and this is very easy to learn naturally without the need for a "Read This" thread.

Comment: your opinion looks more like an outlier compared to what was reported by test group here: [Usability issues for first-time Stack Exchange users - a micro-study](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/165773)